# How to get full request path when using gorilla mux sub router?

Tags: go, gorilla

I am using the gorilla toolkit mux to route requests, i have a couple of subroutes using path prefix, problem is i want to get the full request path but req.URL.path only has the part of the url after the path prefix so how do i get a path including the path prefix? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try [`req.Referer()`](http://godoc.org/net/http#Request.Referer)

It is retrieved from an header value and you are not guaranteed that it is not spoofed.